# Check POST Data - JSON Array

Tags: php, json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I´m trying to check the data of my JSON file. It works for strings in the json file, but how to handle it with arrays in the array?

What i send:

```
{
    "info" : "test",
    "data" : [
        { 
            "startdate": "2018-01-01T10:00:00+0100",
            "enddate": "2018-01-01T17:00:00+0100"
        }
     ]
}
```

What i´ve yet:

```
$dataReq = array(
    'info' => $request->get('info'),
    'date' => $request->get('date'), // my array
);

foreach ($dataReq as $a => $value) {
    if(empty($value)) {
        return new View('The field \''.$a.'\' is required!');     
    }
}
```

But the function `empty` doenst work for arrays so far. It will return false, cause the array is there. How can i check the "startdate" key?

btw: i´m using symfony3(FOSRestBundle), php 7.0

Comment: Is that `#` actually in the sent data or a not?

Comment: Oh sorry. No, it isnt. I´ve edited it.

Comment: did you check the [Symfony Validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) component? I heavily suggest to use it instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @LBA I´ll have a look, thanks.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that in your JSON the key is 'data', then you are trying to get 'date'. Is it like this in your code or this is just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the value is an array and filter null values from it, then test if it's empty.

```
$dataReq = array(
    'info' => $request->get('info'),
    'data' => $request->get('data'), // my array
);

foreach ($dataReq as $a => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) $value = array_filter($value);
    if(empty($value)) {
        return new View('The field \''.$a.'\' is required!');     
    }
}
```

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function's default behavior is to remove from array all values equal to `null`, `0`, `''` or `false` if no callback is passed.

Note: I assume you wanted to retrieve `data` and not `date`.

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389907/check-post-data-json-array/42395809#comment71927777_42389907) by [LBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4716084/lba), I also suggest to check the [Symfony Validation component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) to deal with that instead.

Comment: Yeah. That worked for me so far, i used Symfony Validation, thanks for help.